# Stop datagridview from autoscrolling?

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview in virtual mode that gets quickly populated with data. adding a new row auto scrolls the datagridview to the bottom. Is there anyway to disable this functionality without disabling scroll bars? The user should still be able to scroll around freely as items are added to the grid without it snapping to the bottom.

Edit: Full row select and multi-select are both enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. The answer is to save the current displayed row index and than reset to that index after the datgridview is refreshed. In my case the datagridview is in virtual mode:

```
        Dim saveRow As Integer = 0
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            saveRow = DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex
        End If

        DataGridView1.RowCount = fullitem.Count + 1

        If saveRow < DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
            DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = saveRow
        End If
```